# How to fix CORS error with a POST request for state data of component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, cors, axios

Getting the following error.

[image: ERROR Message]

One possible reason I see is that the data sent is not a pure HTML but I couldn't find how to send (or what exactly is) a pure HTML to be sent in POST request

This is the code I'm using :

```
axios.post(
        "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://ec2-13-231-224-159.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/api/invoice/pdf/generate"
      , this.state.stuff)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      });
    console.log(this.state);
```

There is no server side to contact so I relied on CORS Proxy

Comment: The error message at https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lqo2W.png indicates the real problem is a 503 error.

Answer (score -2):

In order to allow making CORS requests, the API response should contain the valid CORS headers. At least `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` with the URL of your client as the value.
You can also use `*` as the header value **for development purposes only** (don't do so in a production app).

You can read more about CORS in this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)